# Laravel 5.5.45 Unauthenticated with passport

Tags: php, laravel, postman, laravel-passport

Its been more than 3 hours i'm searching for solution.

I have followed https://laravel.com/docs/5.5 docs to install laravel via composer and followed https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport guide for passport to install and configure.

I can generate OAuth tokens fine with postman but no matter what i do it always shows Unauthenticated.

Also i had to run commands below to install passport, because it had issue as well in installation as well.

> composer require paragonie/random_compat:2.* 
>   composer require laravel/passport=~4.0

I tried with multiple installs of laravel and this time i have not modified any laravel code, before i had tried to add days to token expiration which didn't work.

Also have tried these for apache.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

These are the screenshots of postman
[image]

[image]

I'm not sure which code i should share since all i did was just followed official documentation for laravel and passport from laravel site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried multiple times,
There were two issues for me, when i tried first there was no .htaccess file for apache , so even after following all steps on laravel site it always showed me Unauthenticated,

And when i posted the question here i did forget to run `php artisan passport:install` command, 
So all i did was run the command as @ThatCoderGuy said and put .htaccess and its working now.

Answer (score 2):

have you ran `php artisan passport:install` ?

Comment: found the issue because of your answer, posting my answer here :) 
Thanks a million!